# Laravel Time regex

Tags: regex, validation, time, laravel

Working on a regex for time in the format: H:M:S. (00:00:00)

```
'Time' => 'regex:/^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]|60)$/',
```

But getting error: `preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found`

Comment: Works fine: http://regex101.com/r/cN5qH8. Maybe you need to remove the `'regex:'` part

Comment: When using the regex pattern, it may be necessary to specify rules in an array instead of using pipe delimiters, especially if the regular expression contains a pipe character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use array for rules instead of string with pipe as separator:

```
'Time' => array('regex:/^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]|60)$/'),
```

Answer (score 7):

It's much easier to use the [`date_format`](http://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-date-format) validation rule.

e.g.

```
'timeField' => 'required|date_format:H:i',
```